# How can I store an int array in a string variable using ascii values instead the numbers?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, ascii

I'm about to create a word list generator using ascii values of an integer array.

So I initiate the array length like this:

```
int[] array;
int i = 0, j = 65, L = 0;

Console.WriteLine("Enter the length of the word :");
L = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

array = new int[L];

for (i=0; i<L; i++)
{
    array[i] = j;
    j++;
}

for (i=0; i<L; i++)
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("{0} |", (char)array[i]);
}
```

Now the output is gonna be like this:

> Considering that the variable L is equal to 26

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

So, now how could I store all the array component in a single string variable?

Comment: Are you sure you want Ascii instead of Unicode?

Comment: im a biginner Coder thats why i'm using ascii values its all i know in c# 
it has been 2 month since i started learning c#, if ther was any other way to do it i'm glad to learn it too !

Answer (score 2):

Rather than build an `int` array, you could shorten your code to produce a `char` array like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the length of the word :");
var L = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

var array =
    Enumerable
        .Range(65, L)
        .Select(x => (char)x)
        .ToArray();
```

Then the single text value is simple:

```
var text = String.Join(" |", array);
```

Comment: I love Enumerable.Range()